# Custom UITableViewCell subclass update when Core Data updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

I'm using a Core Data model to keep track of some assets and whether they are downloaded to show the download state in the UI. Similar to Spotify's desktop app when you have the + or x or checkmark depending on the state of the player.

I have a custom cell class:

```
// in CellClass.h
@interface CellClass : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *downloadButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CourseType *courseTypeObject;

- (void)updateButtonPictureForStatus:(DownloadState)status;

@end
```

```
// in .m DownloadState is an enum NSUInteger
- (void)updateButtonPictureForStatus:(DownloadState)status {
    if (status == kDOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) {
        [self.downloadButton setImage:DOWNLOADED_PIC forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (status == kNOTDOWNLOADED) {
        [self.downloadButton setImage:NOTDOWNLOADING_PIC forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [self.downloadButton setImage:INPROCESS_PIC forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [self.downloadButton setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"courseTypeObject"]) {
        // when the object is set, add observer
        [self.courseTypeObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isDownloaded" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        if ([change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]) {
            [self.courseTypeObject removeObserver:[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] forKeyPath:@"isDownloaded"];
        }
        ///NSLog(@"should now have a courseTypeObject: %@", self.courseTypeObject);
    }
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isDownloaded"]) {
        if (object != self.courseTypeObject) {
            ///NSLog(@"weird that it got a message that wasn't his");
            return;
        }
        [self updateButtonPictureForStatus:(DownloadState)[[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] intValue]];
        ///NSLog(@"Some cell recieved message from %@ with change to state %@", object, [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]);
    }
}

@end
```

```
// in tableVC.h
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CourseOffering *offering;

@end

// in tableVC.m
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.offering.chapters count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SOTDownloadsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DownloadDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ChapterData *chapter =[self.offering.chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.mainLabel setText:chapter.display_name];
    [cell setCourseTypeObject:chapter];
    [cell updateButtonPictureForStatus:(DownloadState)[[chapter isDownloaded] intValue]];

    return cell;
}
```

Essentially what's happening is that when the Cell gets created, it loads in a subclass of CoureType which is an abstract subclass of NSManagedObject

When that happens, the cell starts KVO on the `isDownloaded` field which is an NSNumber with value 0,1,2 corresponding to the DownloadState enum, but boxed (because Core Data only likes objects and doesn't autobox which is a pain).

CourseType is one of 3 things, either a Chapter, Lesson or Video. A Chapter has many Lessons and a Lesson has many Videos. A Video handles downloading and when it is finished, it changes its isDownloaded to COMPLETE which is @2. The parent lesson is KVO listening for changes in @"isDownloaded" on the child. When all the videos in a lesson are downloaded, the lesson updates isDownloaded, and the parent chapter is listening for those changes.

Now a Cell can hold either a Chapter or a Lesson, and I'd like to be able to autogenerate the NSManagedObject subclasses, so I use categories to extend them. However, this means I can't add protocols or make the cell a delegate of the CourseType object. So as of now, I have the Cell KVO listening for changes in the CourseType object's isDownloaded and it updates its picture accordingly. However, this means that sometimes the Cell is Dealloc'd while still listening.

So either I need to know when to remove the listener from the cell, or alternatively, find a way to update the cell without KVO.

Comment: Are you implementing `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: no. But what would go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unsubscribe to the notifications in dealloc and prepareForReuse things should be safe.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [self.courseTypeObject removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isDownLoaded"];
    self.courseTypeObject = nil;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [_courseTypeObject removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isDownLoaded"];
}
```

(I have not compiled the code, might contain typos)

Comment: Thanks. In dealloc I also had to remove other observers, but it works. I never see prepareForReuseUsed, but maybe it is.

Comment: actually, it gets used in scrolling and seems to work properly.